# Cypress identify a document element inside DOM

Tags: cypress

I have an application that has a document section showing some notes and I am trying to identify and verify the text ("`Release Notes`") with Cypress. But all my locating strategies are failing and need some help. Please see if you can recommend some other way to locate this.

**DOM**:

[image]

**Below is my code:**

```
cy.get('.release-notes')
            .should('be.visible')
            .then((text => {
                cy.log(text.text()) // blank
                cy.log(text) // <span.release-notes>
            }))
       
        cy.get('[data="release-notes.html"]').should('be.visible').then((text => {
            cy.log(text.text()) // blank
            cy.log(text) // <object.release-notes-object>
        }))
        //Below lines - Fails
        //cy.get('h1:contains("Release Notes")') -- Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: h1:contains("Release Notes"), but never found it.
        //cy.get('body').should('contains', "Release Notes"); --Timed out retrying after 4000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but object given
```

Note: I have `"includeShadowDom": true` inside my cypress.json

Answer (score 3):

You may be getting blocked by the `#document`. It does not look like an `iframe`, but may behave like one.

Try

```js
cy.get('object.release-notes-object')
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
  .its('body').should('not.be.undefined').within(() => {

    cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Release Notes')

  })
```

Also turn off chromeWebSecurity in case there's a cross-domain issue

**cypress.json**

```js
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

---

**Debugging the inner document**

Since you can get into the inner document body, in theory you should now be able to query it.

Take a look at the DOM inside body from Cypress' perspective, experiment with timing - the release notes likely to be fetched from a server

```js
cy.get('object.release-notes-object')
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
  .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
  .then($body => {
    cy.wait(10000)        // just for debugging, explicit wait here 
    .then(() => console.log($body[0].innerHTML))  // inspect the elements inside after wait
  })
```

Another way, add a `.should()` to retry

```js
cy.wait(10000)           // for debugging only, waiting for fetch
cy.get('object.release-notes-object')
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
  .its('body', {timeout: 10000})   //vary timeout here
  .should('not.be.undefined') 
  .should('have.descendants', 'h1')  // retries the body fetch until true
```

The difference between the last and adding a timeout to `cy.get('h1')` is that `.should('have.descendants', 'h1')` will re-query the body during each retry.

It's possible that there is an empty body element before the release notes are fetched, and it is replaced when the release notes are added.

Comment: Thank you Mihi., I tried and got this error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: document does not exist on your subject.

cy.its() waited for the specified property document to exist, but it never did.

If you do not expect the property document to exist, then add an assertion such as:`

Comment: As per your latest edit, the `"chromeWebSecurity": false` - already there.

Comment: I amended the code to something that works with an `<iframe>` (verified by test). My hunch is that might work, since the iframe has a `#document` also.

Comment: Good try and unfortunately not working. Error: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: h1, but never found it.`

Comment: Darn, so the contentDocument and <body> lines succeeded? That might just be a timeout issue...

Comment: Well, until body line - all were successful. The `should` itself is an explicit wait and I tried with `cy.get('h1', { timeout: 60000 }).should('contain', 'Release Notes')´` but still it fails at h1.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `"includeShadowDom": true` global flag we have to do something like this:

```js
cy.get('selector').shadow().find('selector')
```

Now may be you can omit the `.shadow()` part and try

```js
cy.get('[app-name="Voyage Planning"]').find('h1:contains("Release Notes")')
```

Comment: Thank you @Alapan. Omitting the global `shadow` flag will force me to rework my 100+ existing good tests

Comment: If you are using `"includeShadowDom": true` than you don't need to add `.shadow`. Or am I getting anything wrong? Can you try this `cy.get('[app-name="Voyage Planning"]').find('h1:contains("Release Notes")')` and see if it works?

Comment: Well, I do not think we have an issue with Shadow elements. As per my guess, cypress may not have support for/documentation on dom inside a dom like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You have attributes `data-gr-ext-installed` and `data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded` on the body. These look like they mark the end of something loading.

Add a check for that in @Mihi's solution (which must be nearly correct).

```js
cy.get('object.release-notes-object')
  .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
  .its('body')
  .should('not.be.undefined')
  .should('have.attr', 'data-gr-ext-installed')  // or data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded
  .within(() => {

    cy.get('h1').should('contain', 'Release Notes')

  })
```

Comment: Thank you @Paolo., it fails at line 3 with error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<body>' to have attribute 'data-gr-ext-installed'`
"